# Paypal Sandbox developers handbook

Tags: paypal

We are developing a new feature to our website "Payment Service", I was going through the https://developer.paypal.com/ website though I have some sample codes I would like to know if there is a developers handbook for reference.

Also would like to know if there is an support for paypal once you sign up to "Sandbox" and implement the service.

Any recommendations are welcome. Thanks in Advance

Comment: There are a lot of developer guides out there, which payment product are you implementing? PayPal Payments Standard, Advanced, Payflow, Payflow Link, Pro, Adaptive Payments, Recurring Billing or button manager? Let me know and I can get you a link to the developer guide.

Comment: Thanks for response, we are looking for the Express Checkout, with Recurring Billing. Thanks in Advance appreciate your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the Developer's Guide for Express Checkout Recurring payments:
[Express Checkout Recurring Payments](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECRecurringPayments/)

Here is the Express Checkout Developer's Guide for Creating Recurring Payment Profile:

[Creating Recurring Payments Profile](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile_API_Operation_NVP/)